# Design Advice on Getter or Const for String in Classes - what are others doing?

Tags: c#

I am seeking some advice on what is the recommend way to use 'constant' strings within my classes, e.g.

```
public string EmployeesString { get { return "Employees";  } }

const string EmployeeString = "Employee";
```

The reason I would like to implement these, i.e. either via a const or via a getter, is because throughout my class(es), I have methods and constructors that use these strings as parameters and I was thinking to avoid typos and also to avoid using strings (weakly-typed?), I wanted to reference them strongly, e.g.

```
DoSomething(this.EmployeeString, employee);
```

What are others doings?  Any advice will be greatly appreciated!  Is this good/bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right" answer, in my opinion, depends on how and why you're using the string.

If the string is being used for display, or presented to a user, then the property is a better design.  This makes it much easier to add localization later by moving the constant into resource files, without having to change your API.  This also makes it easier to adapt your class without breaking other code, since you are free to change the "constant" at any time without breaking other assemblies.

I rarely find appropriate uses for the second case - very few strings are truly constant, and when they are, I believe they're typically better represented as an enumeration instead of a string.  This is almost always better than "magic strings" in your code.

The rare exceptions are typically when interacting with legacy code - if you're dealing with a separate API that is expecting a string, and the string is truly constant, than using a constant is potentially "better", in that it is more efficient and very clear in its intent.

Also, remember that the two approaches can be used together:

```
private const string employeeString = "Employee";

public string EmployeeString { get { return employeeString; } }
```

This allows you to use the constant, making it's intent clear, but easily change this out later without breaking other code or changing your API.  (I personally prefer this to your "second" option above, since the magic string in the property getter is a code smell to me - I like my constants to be obvious constants, but still prefer properties.)

Comment: Great feedback.  I will not be using for the UI layer, but rather trying to use APIs that require string parameters for parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Any strings that you will be using for display or UI work should be put into resource files.  This allows for a strongly typed key, but it also allows for easy internationalization of your application, as you can get the resource file translated to a new language and it will be automatically applied for users of that culture.

For example, if you put a new .resx file into your project called "ApplicationStrings", and added a key/value pair of "EmployeeString"/"Employee" to it, you could call it in your application like this:

```
DoSomething(ApplicationStrings.EmployeeString, employee);
```

If you created a translated version of these strings, let's say for Mexican Spanish, you would just create a new file called ApplicationStrings.es-mx.resx.  When people with the es-mx culture setting used your program, it would automatically use the translated version!

So the advantages are pretty clear - strongly referenced values, easy localization, and centralized management of magic strings in your application.

Even for strings that won't end up being displayed, I usually create resource files for them anyway, like "InternalStrings.resx".  This way you can use strongly typed references to internal "magic strings" that your program might need, and if you need to change them, you only have to change the value in one place.

Comment: Exactly. How best to do this depends completely on whether the string is for signalling within your assembly, signalling outside your assembly, storage in a database, or for UI work. +1

Comment: @Sanjay - good point, there is significantly more to think about for internationalization than just translated files. Resourcing strings is a good first step for cleaning up your application code for it though, and a good habit to get into.

Comment: +1: There are (rare) places where I feel that constant strings make sense, but as I said in my answer, they are rare  - otherwise, I agree 100%, and nice job on flushing out details of the advantages of resource strings.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings could ever change in the future you have to be a little bit careful with making them const, at least if they're accessible to other assemblies, otherwise the other assemblies might not pick up the new value if you create a new version of the assembly.

Edit: Added missing words

Comment: If I build against your assembly and reference your constant, the value of the const gets inlined into my code.  You change your const value and release a new version and bad things can happen.

Comment: @Will: Yes, that's what I wanted to say, but I think I suffer from temporary dyslexia or something :)

Answer (score 2):

If it is truly a constant I do this:

```
const string EmployeeString = "Employee";
```

It is by far the easiest way of telling other programmers, "This isn't going to change."

```
public string EmployeesString { get { return "Employees";  } }
```

Without seeing inside the code, I don't know what is going to happen in the accessor.  I just know that there is an accessor, and I'm getting a string back.  Later on in this example too, someone could add a set property etc. and change the value of the property at runtime.  You can't do that with a constant.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about, at least in this example would be a "Constant".  Therefore the second method would be the "most appropriate" at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

const field is correct